# I want to convert columns to rows based on the condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My sql query returns the below output.

[image]

In C#.Net i have to convert it like below based on RowSequence and ColumnSequence column values.
[image]

How to do it.

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried any code as i didn't know how to write code for this.

Comment: Instead of Posting Image better you could create some script for  Dummy table and records .So we can help you easily.@Dotnetpickles

Comment: When u say in C# .Net convert u think LINQ ?

Comment: Wow.  You should really learn how to use a database properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use dynamic pivot as your row value that needs to pivoted is not fixed:

```
DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @columns = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from YOURTABLE
                    group by ColumnName, ColumnSequesnce
                    order by ColumnSequesnce
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @columns + N' from 
             (
                select RowSequence, ColumnValue, ColumnName
                from YOURTABLE
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(ColumnValue)
                for ColumnName in (' + @columns + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: EventName,EventPlace and EventDay are just for example. Actually this values are dynamic. In some cases it is 3 columns. but it may go upto 10 columns. In that case how i can do?

Comment: @Dotnetpickles then you have to go with pivot

Comment: @Dotnetpickles try changed query

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `Pivot` in Sql

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Try it.